# Please verify that the subreport has been published and that the name is correct

Tags: c#, report-viewer2010

I've been searching for days and cannot find a solution.

I have a RDLC sub report (VS2010) which Works fine in the environment/local mode, also works fine when I deploy to our Development server.  However, when I deploy to the Production server, I get the following error.

The subreport 'Emp' could not be found at the specified location
 \folder\folder\UK\weba\web\wwwroot\folder\Reports\RDLC\Emp.rdlc. 
Please verify that the subreport has been published and that the name is correct.

If I take the path above it actually finds Emp.rdlc so confused.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using an absolute path? If not you could try that. I'd imagine that might have something to do with it. I know I was having issues with relative/absolute paths when I deployed to production for my first time.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the confusing thing is the MAIN report and sub report are in the same folder the main report displays fine yet the sub report can not be found. If this was due to relative/absolute paths I think it would affect the Main report as well. Thanks again for responding.

Comment: Has the subreport been published? (I'm guessing you checked but sometimes the obvious fix doesn't always seem so obvious). Sorry if I'm not being much help, I'm not too familiar with subreports, researching a bit on them now though.

Comment: Princesszea ,Are you resolve  this problem? I'm waiting your answer. I have a problem like you.